# Вежды, видеть, ведать — этимология

Tags: этимология

Согласно [Фасмеру](https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D0%B2/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0), старославянское слово "в**ѣ**жды (вежды, веки)" образовно от глагола "в**и**деть", по аналогии с "р**ѣ**чь" -> "нар**и**цать".

Может ли данное слово также быть этимологически одкоренным для глагола "вѣдати(ведать)", учитывая наличие в старославянском чередования д->жд, например, вѣдати ->невѣжда?

Answer (score 1):

Сведение, ведение, природо**ведение**... - от глагола "ведать", а не "видеть". 
Видеть - действие глаза. Ведать - это область сознания; точнее, одно из делений понятия "знание".